# Finding Files in Directory With Specific Letters

Tags: java, android, android-studio, file, sharedpreferences

I am listing all the files in the "shared prefs" directory of an app. There are 3 shared prefs in total: "User.xml" and "Note_1.xml" and "Note_2.xml".

```
File f = new File("/data/data/com.bhiruva/shared_prefs/");
String[] pathnames;
pathnames = f.list();
```

That is the code I am using for listing all the files in that folder, but I need to list the files which only have the title starting as "note_"...

Can someone please tell me how to do this? Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
for(String pathname:pathnames){
    if(pathname.startsWith("Note_")){
        //do something
    }
}
```

Comment: But how do I print the files that start with "note_"?

Comment: Just create a new File object based on the path then use a FileInputStream to read it

Answer (score 0):

Use a FilenameFilter to accept only the disired files:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FilenameFilter;

....

File f = new File("/data/data/com.bhiruva/shared_prefs/"); 

String[] pathnames = f.list(new FilenameFilter() {
    @Override
    public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
       return name.toLowerCase().startsWith("note_");
    }
});
```

Or shorter using lambdas if you are using Java 8 or higher

```
File f = new File("/data/data/com.bhiruva/shared_prefs/"); 

String[] pathnames = f.list((dir, name) -> name.toLowerCase().startsWith("note_"));
```